# Unable to start application server of pgadmin 4

Tags: windows, pgadmin-4

I have just installed postgresql-10.4-1-windows-x64. Didn't face any issue while installation, however, when trying to open pgAdmin4 receiving an error as attached.

[image]

Please help to get this started.

Comment: How were you opening pgAdmin4 (assuming ver3.0)? What path?

Comment: opening it from the apps section on windows 8.

Comment: No I mean where is your PGadmin? Like "C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\pgAdmin4.exe" - just need to be sure you're running the latest version. Also what default browser and is browser also latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have an earlier version of pgAdmin installed? The reason I ask is because the error message you received indicates you might be launching a different version than 4.3.

There was a rewrite so the old runtime as a tray-based server (v4.2 & older) is now launched a web browser (v 4.3 feature [#3086](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/3086)).

I suspect your error not being able to connect to the "*application server*" means you are launching an older version but downloaded a newer one.

Comment: No, this is the 1st attempt I have tried with no luck. Post this error uninstalled the 10.4 and installed 9.6 with that to the same error. Not getting any thread to resolve this error. With the same process of installation on another computer, its perfectly working. Not sure why it is showing an error on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

while mine is the 32 bit version, i encountered the same problem. but i solved mine by adding the postgresql bin folder path to the environment variable settings.